# How do you return a value from a called function to the main?

Tags: c

I use the return command then try to print the value from the main. It returns a value of zero (0).

This program is about temperature conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

Also how can you use a rounding function to round the answer to an integer so it is not a floating point number with decimals.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Cel_To_Fah(int a, int b); // function declaration

int main (void)

{

    int a;
    int b;

    printf(" Enter temperatrure:  "); scanf("%d", &a);

    Cel_To_Fah(a,b); // function call

    printf("The temperature is: %d\n", b);

    return 0;

} // main

int Cel_To_Fah(a,b)

{

    b=1.8*a+32;

    return b;

} // Cel_To_Fah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of second argument to function(b).

You can do this by...

```
      #include<stdio.h>
    int Cel_To_Fah(int a); // function declaration, as it returns a values;


     int main (void)
       {
       int a; int b;

       printf(" Enter temperatrure: "); 
       scanf("%d", &a);
       b = Cel_To_Fah(a); /* the returned value is stored into b, and as b is an integer so it is automatically rounded. no fraction point value can be stored into an integer*/
       printf("The temperature is: %d\n", b);
       return 0;
       } // main

     int Cel_To_Fah(int a)
       {
       return 1.8 * a + 32;
       }
```

Answer (score 6):

You just have to use the assignment operator:

```
b = Cel_To_Fah(a);
```

Your program has a lot of problems, though, including your `Cel_To_Fah` function not having a correct signature.  You probably want something like:

```
int Cel_To_Fah(int a)
{
    return 1.8 * a + 32;
}
```

You should probably get a good beginner C book.

Comment: Or `printf("The temperature is: %d\n", Cel_To_Fah(a,b) );`

Comment: Well, my implementation doens't *have* a `b`, but yes, you can do that.

Comment: Because the `b` in your `Cel_To_Fah` is not the same `b` as in `main`.  C is a pass-by-value language.

Comment: There are rounding functions in `math.h`.

Answer (score 1):

there are several issues.  First you need to use float, not int, so that you can have values with a decimal point. otherwise your calculations will come out wrong.  Also use 32.0 instead of 32 for the same reason.

Second, you need to understand that the a and b in your function are NOT the same as the a and b in main.  They have the same name but are not in the same "scope".  So changing the one in your function doesn't affect the one in main.  That's why in main you have to say b=Cel...  so that b in main will get the returned value.

finally, in c, you're supposed to put your functions above/before main.  Otherwise it's technically not defined "yet", though some modern compilers will fix that for you.  Read about function prototypes.

Comment: well back in my day we'd just do (int)(b+.5)

Comment: but for handling negative numbers which you will have, you better do int round_b = (b - floor(b) > 0.5) ? ceil(b) : floor(b);  which is just an if() statement

Answer (score 0):

Since your function `Cel_To_Fah(a,b);` is returning a value (`int` type), you must have to assign it to a variable of its return type (`int` type).

```
 int a;
 int b;

printf(" Enter temperatrure:  "); scanf("%d", &a);

b = Cel_To_Fah(a); // function call

printf("The temperature is: %d\n", b);
```

and your function should be

```
int Cel_To_Fah(a)
{
    int b = 1.8*a+32;
    return b;
 } // Cel_To_Fah
```

And do not forget to change your function prototype to

```
int Cel_To_Fah(int a);
```

Comment: @haccks I don't downvote just incorrect answers; I also downvote ones I find unhelpful. Your original answer contained no code, which in my opinion made it a poor answer for a novice programmer. It's nothing personal. Your revised answer is just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I saw two issues in your code. Firstly, it is variable type. I assume that you want Celsius as integer; but Fahrenheit = 1.8*Celsius+32 should be float. Therefore b should be float.

Secondly, you should not return a value from a function via its input parameters (unless you learn pointer or call by ref). I rewrite your code as following:

```
include<stdio.h>

float Cel_To_Fah(int a); // function declaration

int main (void)

{

    int a;
    float b;

    printf(" Enter temperatrure:  "); scanf("%d", &a);

    b=Cel_To_Fah(a); // function call

    printf("The temperature is: %.2f\n", b);  //showing 2 decimal places

    return 0;

} // main

float Cel_To_Fah(int a)

{
    float b;

    b=1.8*(float)a+32;   //cast a from int to float

    return b;

} // Cel_To_Fah
```